# Converting password to star *

Tags: c#

I'm just messing around in visual Studio C# at the moment and just wondering how can I convert a password inserted in a text box into stars. Here's the code and any help appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Email = TxtEmail.Text;
        string Password = TxtPassword.Text;

        if (Email == "test@gmail.com" && Password == "LOL")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Complete");
        }
        else if (Email == "hotmail@lol.co.uk" && Password == "Lol")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Complete");
        }
        else if (Email == "eg@eg.co.uk" && Password == "eg")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Complete");
        }
        else if (Email == "" && Password == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed", "Login Failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [TextBox.PasswordChar Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx)

> Gets or sets the character used to mask characters of a password in a
>   single-line TextBox control.

Example from MSDN:

```
public void CreateMyPasswordTextBox()
 {
    // Create an instance of the TextBox control.
    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
    // Set the maximum length of text in the control to eight.
    textBox1.MaxLength = 8;
    // Assign the asterisk to be the password character.
    textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
    // Change all text entered to be lowercase.
    textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Lower;
    // Align the text in the center of the TextBox control.
    textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
 }
```